# Mysql Result set Error

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I am executing a block of code where I need to retrieve a set of users from database and do some stuff with them. Very simple scenario.
The problem is that although I use `while(rs.next())` , when `rs.next()` reaches null my program tries to continue with the code inside while clause and exits with Null Exception.

Why is that happening? Is something broken in my code that I cannot figure out?
Please, notice that `rs` is never `null`. At the beginning prints at the console all the contents of `rs` but when it reaches the end it returns null exception.

```
   try {                       
      String sql = "select distinct userid from userinfo";
      stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
      try (ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery(sql)) {
         while (rs.next()) {
            String mentionsIDs = (rs.getString("mentions")).trim();

            try{
               if (!mentionsIDs.isEmpty() ){
                  System.out.println(mentionsIDs);
                  String[] arr = mentionsIDs.split("\\s+");
                  if(isNumeric(arr[0])){
                     System.out.println(arr[0]);
                     sources.add(Long.parseLong(arr[0]));
                  }
               }            
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
               Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
         }   
         rs.close();
      }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are returning only the distinct userids and reading `mentions` column ? `(rs.getString("mentions")).trim()` could throw a `NullPointerException` is `rs.getString("mentions")` is null

Comment: You were completely right!! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: `rs.close()` is no longer needed because of the `try(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `String mentionsIDs = (rs.getString("mentions")).trim();` inside the try block then catch `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

You must also check that the result set indeed have some results in it. Put a condition over your while loop which checks that rs is not null.

```
if(rs!=null) {
    while(rs.next()) {
        ... Process
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("The query returned 0 results");
}
```

In your code:

```
String sql = "select distinct userid from userinfo";
stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
try (ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery(sql)) {
      if(rs!=null) {
      while (rs.next()){
      String mentionsIDs = (rs.getString("mentions")).trim();
      try{
          if (!mentionsIDs.isEmpty() ){
                System.out.println(mentionsIDs);
                String[] arr = mentionsIDs.split("\\s+");
                if(isNumeric(arr[0])){
                   System.out.println(arr[0]);
                   sources.add(Long.parseLong(arr[0]));
                }
          }
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
          Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }   
   rs.close();
   }
```